# how to change part of a file name to something else on mutilple files

Tags: echo

I'm making a game to help learn commands and I have directories that will all have the same number of files of different types in them. I need to be able to change part of the file name in each directory so it signifies that it is in deed a file from that directory.

e.g,

Dir 1 name "Orange"
file 1 name: "water_orange.jpeg"
file 2 name:  1_water_orange.jpeg"
etc, etc 15 files

Dir 2 name "Indigo"
file 1 name: "water_indigo.jpeg"
file 2 name: "1_water_indigo.jpeg"
etc etc 15 files

I have 7 directories with 15 files in each and I want to see if it's possible to change the colour part of the file name in each directory, without have to use the "mv" command on each individual file.

I've tried the "echo sed" command with both single and double quotes but no luck

i.e. echo sed "s/orange/indigo/g"  and echo sed 's/orange/indigo/g'

any help sincerely appreciated

Comment: see the man pages for `rename.ul` and `rename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
for i in $(ls *.jpeg)
do 
mv -v $i $(ls $i | sed 's/orange/indigo/')
done
```

But this *very* clumsy syntax can be *enormously* improved, as steeldriver has suggested in the comments below, with the following elegant syntax:

```
for i in *.jpeg; do mv -v -- "$i" "${i/orange/indigo}"; done
```

Bear in mind that both of these examples are for single directories, and are not recursive...

Comment: Thank you so much. I've no idea what your code means at this point but in time I'm hopeful.  On with the Games!!! Cheers

Comment: IMHO there is no need **ever** to use `for i in $(ls *.jpeg)`. Using `for i in *.jpeg; do mv -v -- "$i" "${i/orange/indigo}"; done` would be more efficient (avoiding THREE unnecessary external program calls) and would also work for files with whitespace in their names.

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed my answer is more than a little ugly! I shall remove it so your own more elegant answer can be placed... Oops looks like I cannot...

Comment: @andrew.46 feel free to edit yours and I will upvote it

Comment: @steeldriver All done, and thanks for the syntax which I am using extensively for my own use :)